# Why is there a hole in return duct

Tags: hvac

There's a hole in return duct going under my house; why?

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I've fixed the image and tweaked your text, but we'll still need more info. Does air rush into the hole when the furnace is running? Is there an air supply duct in that space?

Comment: This may have been left for make up air, normally these have a screen over them and are not larger than 2-4", I usually see a damper or adjustable plate over the hole to fine tune the system.

Comment: Air does come in , I don't think there is a air supply duct around but I'm not 100%, I just bought the house and being a single parent I haven't had the time to get under there

Comment: So I shouldn't cover that hole and just use some sort of screen

Comment: It looks like shoddy workmanship to me. I would seal it, or at the very least, screen it.

Comment: Do you have a full basement, or a crawlspace?

Comment: I have a crawlspace